# Never-ending https loop

Tags: https, security, add-on

I'm using Noscript and found out that it has a function to force sites to use a secure connection, I tried forcing a few sites but when I try going to any of them I get a blank tab and my status bar acts like it's constantly reloading.
I had a Greasemonkey script that forced secure connection before I found the Noscript option but the Greasemonkey script didn't give me any trouble.
Any idea what's going on? the only thing I can think of is they request secure connection differently and Noscript's doing it wrong, and I don't think that's quite right.

To be more specific:
Noscript is having trouble displaying some of the exact same sites over a secure connection as the Greasemonkey script.

Answer (score 2):

Some websites will redirect their SSL main page to their non-secure page in the effort to save a few CPU cycles so that they don't have the overhead from the SSL encryption/decryption. If you then force it back to the SSL version you are getting an infinite loop.